# Map-overlay balloon close

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application in which i need to set itemize overlay and ballon popup in google mapview so simply i have just continue with [This](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) and it going good for me.now when i tap on overlayitem, it get balloon with attach data (with help of inflater) now on that inflater file i set one close button wich apear at top of the balloon. so when click on close , balloon will be close. but here i am stuck with event that how can i close this balloon at click event.

if it is separate activity then i can defiantly close with simply call finish() method.

but here differant matter...so please help me out this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use android-mapviewballoons. He has a great & useful library for us to use in Google Maps.

[image]

Here is his repo: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons